# AttributeError: module 'skimage.transform' has no attribute 'seam_carve'

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, scikit-image

code:

```
from skimage import transform
from skimage import filters
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

img = cv2.imread('/content/seam.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
plt.imshow(img)

for i in range(20, 180, 20):
    carved_image = transform.seam_carve(img, filtered,'horizontal' i)
```

I receive the following error:

```
AttributeError: module 'skimage.transform' has no attribute 'seam_carve'
```

I am trying to implement seam carved algorithm.
I am using Python 3.8 and the scikit-image is 0.18.1. I also tried the scikit-image version of 0.15.0 as it was suggested somewhere but none of the version worked.

Comment: Why do you think seam_carve exists in skimage?  I do not see it at https://scikit-image.org/docs/0.18.x/api/skimage.transform.html. It is not listed in transform after version 0.14. Perhaps it was moved or removed. Likely removed since it is patented.

Comment: Can I try version 0.14.x then?

Comment: You can try. You have my permission. https://scikit-image.org/docs/0.14.x/api/skimage.transform.html

Answer (score 2):

The `seam_carve` function was removed from `scikit-image` as of version 0.15.x since the used algorithm is patented, cf. [the corresponding GitHub issue](https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/issues/3646).

[The latest version of `scikit-image` providing `seam_carve` seems to be 0.14.3.](https://scikit-image.org/docs/0.14.x/api/skimage.transform.html#skimage.transform.seam_carve)